# Create a symlink to a serial port

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, serial

I have a software that outputs some info to a text file. Now I want to redirect that output to a serial port. The file name is hard coded in the software. So I decided to create a symlink to the serial port. The symlink will have the same name as the file.
I tried:

```
mklink file.txt COM1
```

The symlink was successfuly created but whenever I try to write something to that file.txt, a COM1 file is created in the same directory. So all the output goes to that file instead of the serial port.

Is it possible to create a symlink to a serial port in Windows?

Comment: Did you try the UNC path for the port?

Comment: I wonder if you need to specify it like `"COM1:9600,N,8,1"`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I tried `\\.\COM1`. Such a link doesn't work. System error 4392 when openning the file

Comment: @FalconMomot It still creates a COM1 file in the same directory

Comment: I think that `\\.\COM1` needs a colon after it in order to work: so it should be `\\.\COM1:`, but I don't know if that will solve your problem, because I don't know if it will let you make a symlink, even with that.